# How does null infinity differ from ordinary infinity?

Tags: spacetime, causality, topology

Null infinity is the diagonal lines on the edge of a Penrose diagram. It [seems to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_infinity) the place where beams of light go if they never bump into anything, but only light can go there. It appears to be the "other end" of the null cone. This sounds  <s>crazy</s>   counterintuitive. But is it correct?

Because the upper diagonal line in this doesn't look like the path of a geodesic:

[image: pic]

Assuming it is, my question: *how does that differ from regular infinity?*

Comment: What do you mean by "regular infinity" ?

Comment: @SolubleFish: see the picture.

Comment: There is no “regular infinity” in the picture, whatever that is supposed to mean. There are past and future timelike infinity, past and future null infinity, and spacelike infinity.

Answer (score 3):

By ordinary infinity, do you mean the infinity of an infinitely distant point? That would be the spacelike infinity.

Do you mean the infinite from waiting an infinitely long time? That would be the timelike infinity.

The Penrose diagram compresses these into points. This is just a distortion that is useful, somewhat like the various distortions you get from printing a map of the Earth on flat paper. Here is a good explanation from PBS Space Time [Mapping the Multiverse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v9A9hQUcBQ)

---

Update: PBS Space Time made several videos on rotating black holes. I haven't found the one I want, that goes into detail about Penrose coordinates. Other videos have bits and pieces. Here are some.

- [What’s On The Other Side Of A Black Hole?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4oYvSH6jJ8)
- [White Holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4aqGI1mSqo)
- [How Time Becomes Space Inside a Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KePNhUJ2reI)

---

Update 2: On taking a second look, your diagram appears to be a bit different from a Penrose diagram. A number of similar coordinate systems are used for this. They all show one spatial dimension and time. Space is a ray from the center of the black hole radially out to infinity. For example, in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, the left edge is $r=0$.

[image]

Your diagram appears to be a portion of a Penrose diagram, except that the left edge would be the world line of your current position from the infinite past to the infinite future. Here is a bigger portion.

[image]

The screenshots are from [What’s On The Other Side Of A Black Hole?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4oYvSH6jJ8). The blue curves have constant $r$. The red/violet curves have constant $t$. Yellow is light, always at $45^o$.

In the Penrose diagram, you are right now at the event at the center of our universe. The horizontal line halfway up is the radial ray from the event horizon to infinity at the current time.

Various rays of light are right now directed radially outward at various points along the ray. These would be upward and to the right. The future cosmic horizon is the infinitely distant point where the rays wind up in the infinitely distant future.

These rays might have originated in the infinitely distant past from the horizon on the lower left. The similar horizon on the lower right is where light rays directed radially inward might have originated.

See the videos for more. There are some animations that trace the path of an infalling observer in real space time and the diagram. They explain why time and space are reversed in the black hole interior, what happens when rotation is added, and more.

Comment: The Penrose diagram compresses these into points. === see the pic. the entire  distance between spacelike and timelike infinities is null infinity. So is it a null surface, or what?