# Is it possible to refind entry trajectory after leaving a rotating black hole?

Tags: black-holes, geodesics, kerr-metric

I'm asking about the case where an infalling object travels a path right through a rotating black hole, intact.

I want to provide a simple parallel for the purposes of question clarity:

A horse can take me from my house to a paddock, from Point *a* to Point *b*. Something then spooks the horse, a descending hot air balloon (for example) and it bolts far into the woods, going from Point *b* to Point *c*. While I'm unfamiliar with that section of the woods, the horse eventually calms down and I'm able to use a compass to return us both to my house. Going from Point *c* to Point *a* is journey I've never taken before. I can then go from Point *a* to Point *b* again if I wish.

Now, consider my approach to a rotating black hole from a space station, using a craft that produces thrust. At a suitable distance from the space station I disengage the thrust mechanism and allow the craft to drift from there, Point *A*, to the event horizon which I'm calling Point *B* (anywhere on the horizon). Presuming that the craft passes through any ringlike singularity and I'm not obliterated by infinite blue-shifting, I could emerge from the event horizon and travel far enough away so that I can regain control of the craft, a place I call Point *C*.

My question is, would I then be able to go from Point *C* to Point *A*, avoiding the black hole?

Secondarily, would I be able to go from Point *A* to Point *B* again, refinding my original trajectory?

Comment: In my answer to [How does null infinity differ from ordinary infinity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/807415/37364), there are some links to videos that talk about what happens to an observer that falls into a rotating black hole.

Comment: @mmesser314 The "Mapping The Multiverse" link is most relevant, addressing the question by predicting that the exterior is not accessible from the interior and that the interior can lead to places wholly disconnected from the exterior. Weird stuff, but interesting to a certain degree.